# JQM - Button clicks from multiple pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile app, that loads pages in via ajax eg page1.html, page2.html etc

On page1.html I have a button:

```
<a href="page2.html" data-role="button" class="submit">Submit</a>
```

On page2.html I also have a button

```
 <a href="page3.html" data-role="button" class="submit">Submit</a>
```

I have a script file (script.js) referenced on each page inside the body with the following code:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function(){
    console.log('new page');
    $('.submit').on('click', function(){
      console.log($('this'));
    });
}
```

'new page' is being written to the console for each page but the click is only being registered on a single page (if I refresh the page it works on that page only)

Any ideas on how to get the click to be fired on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selector param of `.on()` , in that case you need to bind the event only **once**, so do it in the `document.ready()` handler instead, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(){
      console.log($('this'));
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked but I switched the ready() function for pageload(). The only problem I now have is that 'new page' gets fired multiple times on each page load, minimum 2 sometime 10 or more?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery mobile, you should use the event `pageinit` as an equivalent to the traditional `onload`. The code below should do the trick.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    console.log('new page');
    $('.submit').on('click', function(){
      console.log($('this'));
    });
}
```